# ASP.NET MVC 3 check if validation on page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

How would I check if a form / page had validation on it?

e.g.

```
 if ($('.uiModalContent > form') HAS VALIDATION) {
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('.uiModalContent');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A mild shot in the dark here but you could potentially check if

```
$(this).valid() == null //'this' is your form of course

//or

jQuery.Validator == null //global though, not form specific
```

Why not just parse the content anyways?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but you could count the number of validation rules in the validate object. Maybe something like this:

```
function HasValidation(selector){
    var propCount = 0;
    for(var prop in $(selector).validate().settings.rules){
         propCount++;
    }
    return propCount > 0;
}
```

and then in your if statement call:

```
HasValidation('.uiModalContent > form')
```

Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while searching for the answer to it myself with little success. so i started playing with firebug and some forms and came up with:

```
    if ($('#myform').data('validator') != null) {

        console.log('has validator');
    }
    else {
        console.log('no validator');
    }
```